# What are the differences betwen immutable and mutable classes?

Tags: class

i studing about c# and i think that the diference betwen mutable & inmutable class , (un c# for example), are that the definitión of the variables cant change. The string still string, or may be that the value of the types cant change : string =  "Hola" still "Hola". and the mutable can change.
well i am right or what is the real diference?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An immutable object is an object that can't change it's property values after it's created (actually its state, but to simplify, let's just assume that a different state implies different property/variable values). Any properties are usually asigned values in the constructor (it may not have any properties at all, just methods).

An immutable object can have internal variables that might change values, as long as they don't affect the state of that object from a public/external point of view.

A `string` in C# is immutable... if you try to assign a `string` variable a different value, a new `string` is created.

You can find more information about immutability in OOP on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

**PS**: it's a bit more complicated than this, but I don't want to confuse you... there are different levels of what can be considered "immutable", but if you want to research further, apart from the Wikipedia article (which doesn't mention C#), there's [this post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) which explains the different types way better than I could ever do.